# java: while loop breaks

Tags: java, while-loop

This loop breaks if uncomment 2 commented string, cannot figure out why it happens, help plz:

```
private static String findAll(String cell, ArrayList<String> hrange, ArrayList<String> vrange, List<String> cellrange, Integer cycle){
        cellrange.add(cell);
        String color = XldocReader.xlCells.get(cell);
        String[] chkeys = cell.split("\\$");
        String chLetter = chkeys[1];
        Integer chNumber = Integer.parseInt(chkeys[2]);
        boolean rcnext = false;
        boolean rcprev = false;
        Iterator<String> ite = hrange.iterator();
        while ( ite.hasNext() ) {
            String candidate = ite.next();
            String value = XldocReader.xlCells.get(candidate);
            String[] ckeys = candidate.split("\\$");
            String cLetter = ckeys[1];
            int n = getKeyByValue(chLetter);

            String next = cell.replaceAll(chLetter+"", columns.get(n+1) +"");
            String cnext = XldocReader.xlCells.get(next);
            String prev = cell.replaceAll(chLetter+"", columns.get(n-1) +"");
            String cprev = XldocReader.xlCells.get(prev);
            //rcnext = cnext.equals(color);
            //rcprev = cprev.equals(color);
            ...
        }
        return cellrange.toString();
  }
```

it should find equals strings and run recursively check again but on first check it's breaks and nothing check more...

Comment: Please post the exception stack trace you're getting with this code

Comment: Do you mean "break" as in there are no more iterations of the loop, or as in there is an exception thrown?

Comment: yap, it breaks as no more iterations

Answer (score 0):

I would make the loop

```
for(String candidate : hrange) {

}
```

And I would step through the code in a debugger to see exactly what it is doing as I suspect you program isn't doing what you think it is.

What do you mean by breaks?  What is the Exception and on which line does it occur?  Does it match what you see in the debugger?

I suspect the problem is in the code you have labelled as `...`

Comment: Iterator<String> ite = hrange.iterator();
it has 4 elements in first action, in next call it has 1 element, next 6 elements. and it should iterate through all elements but it's not, just stop after first check in second action

Comment: What does it do after it stops the loop? Are you sure its not throwing an Exception?

Comment: it just return cell and stop. just iterate one loop and exit.

Comment: exits the loop and steps to next instruction out side the loop or exits the program?

Comment: Which means an Exception was probably thrown which you are ignoring somewhere in your code.

Comment: so now you need to look at the line which throws the exception. i.e. make sure to print or log this type of exception. e.printStackTrace();  I would use your debugger to stop when this exception is thrown.

Comment: i'm getting NullPointerException in rcnext = cnext.equals(color); and rcprev = cprev.equals(color);

Comment: You can only get an exception on one of those lines. Which one is it?  You then need to determine why that value is `null` (I suspect its `cnext`)

Answer (score 0):

Can you give us more info? What the error is? How it breaks? etc. Also, print out the results of color and cnext, cprev right before it breaks.

My guess is those are not legit strings. And you are trying to run an equals method on something that is not a legit string.

Comment: color = #ff0000 cnext = #ffff00 cprev = #99cc00

Comment: My guess is there is an error and you are catching it. Does not make sense otherwise.